# JSON Array response REST API, Error extracting data c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, serialization

I am trying to extract from a response, but when trying to DeserializeObject I get the following error.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'JSonClasses+Item' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
>   {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.

My Response is:

```
[{"Odid":45606,"UserId":22728,"FirstName":"FirstName ","MiddleName":null,"LastName":"LastName","UserName":"FirstName.LastName","ExternalEmail":"email@yahoo.com","DefinedId":"12345","UniqueIdentifier":"null","Activation":{"IsActive":true},"DisplayName":"FirstName LastName"}]
```

Here is how I am trying to DeserializeObject this response:

```
public class Activation
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int OrgId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ExternalEmail { get; set; }
    public string OrgDefinedId { get; set; }
    public string UniqueIdentifier { get; set; }
    public Activation Activation { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}


var responceID= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSonClasses.Item>(response.Content);
```

I also have tried to use the following method to convert it into a Dynamic object and then try to extract data into Item class but the same error occurs:

```
dynamic response2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, the deserializer cannot deserialize the *array* into your class that requires an *object*. Your JSON response is actually an array of one object and must be deserialized as such.

You need to deserialize the response into an array or list of `JsonClasses.Item` instead of into a single one, e.g.:

```cs
List<JSonClasses.Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSonClasses.Item>>(response.Content);
```

As an additional note, there is a mismatch between `"Odid"` in your posted response body and `OrgId` in your Item class, which may cause your deserialization to still fail.